# What instruments or avionics do balloons usually have?

Tags: flight-instruments, lighter-than-air, balloon

For normal sightseeing flights in a typical hot air balloon, what instruments or avionics does the pilot usually carry? Do balloons have a minimum equipment list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic regulation for minimum equipment on a balloon (in the USA) is [14CFR31.85 ("Required Basic Equipment" for manned free-air balloons)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:1.0.1.3.15&idno=14#14:1.0.1.3.15.6.363.4).

The FAA requires that balloons be equipped with:

#### For all balloons

> 1. [Reserved]
> 2. An altimeter.
> 3. A rate of climb indicator.

#### For hot air balloons (additional equipment):

> 1. A fuel quantity gauge.
> 2. An envelope temperature indicator.

#### For captive gas balloons (additional equipment):

> - A compass.

---

Beyond what's required by regulation, in most free balloon operations I've seen they also carry an aviation radio and/or a CB radio (to communicate with their ground crew) - this is usually a handheld transceiver.

[The FAA Balloon Flying Handbook](http://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/media/faa-h-8083-11.pdf) also makes for interesting reading. They talk about required and optional instruments and equipment found on various types of balloons in Chapter 2.

Comment: Additionally, to fly in controlled airspace: an aviation radio and a transponder. (BMA in Stockholm Sweden)